# Windows 10 Hyper-V Manager connecting to Hyper-V Server 2012

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I am trying to connect to Hyper-V Server 2012 with Windows 10 Hyper-V manager.

The Hyper-V server is not in a domain and the Windows 10 Pro is in a domain.

Following this [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/remotely-manage-hyper-v-hosts) does not work. I am getting the following error:

> This version of the Hyper-V Management Tools cannot be used to manage servers running Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2 as another user.

Googling around couldn't find a solution.

Anyone encountered the same issue and found a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. The reason is already in both the error message:

> This version of the Hyper-V Management Tools cannot be used to manage
>   servers running Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2 as
>   another user.

and the [Remotely manage Hyper-V hosts with Hyper-V Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/remotely-manage-hyper-v-hosts) article you linked in your question:

> Connect to a Windows 2016 or Windows 10 remote host as a different
>   user
>
> **Note**: This will only work for Windows Server 2016 or Windows 10 remote
>   hosts.

I don't know if anyone can state this more clearly...

Solutions:

- Join both to an AD domain and use the same user.
- Use RDP and run Hyper-V Manager on the server.
- Upgrade to Windows Server 2016.